# How does rails know what :something is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code

```
form.label :artists
```

which outputs

```
<label for="artist_artist_name">Artist name</label>
```

How did rails find the strings `artist_artist_name` and `Artist name`?

In general, how can I track this kind of information down?

I have tried grep -ri artists * in the project root but there is no result (apart from `form.label :artists`). Same for `Artist name`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form helper is used as in the following snippet:

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :first_name %>:
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %><br />

  <%= f.label :last_name %>:
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %><br />

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

What follows `f.label` or `f.text_field` is the identifier of a property for the object referred by `@person`.

The CSS ID you notice is simply obtained concatenating the name of the variable with an underscore, and the property name; the label is obtained replacing the underscores in the property with spaces, and rewriting the first word in capital case.

The code I reported would generate the following HTML (I removed the parts that were not important).

```
<form action="/people" class="new_person" id="new_person" method="post">
  <label for="person_first_name">First name</label>:
  <input id="person_first_name" name="person[first_name]" size="30" type="text" /><br />

  <label for="person_last_name">Last name</label>:
  <input id="person_last_name" name="person[last_name]" size="30" type="text" /><br />

  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Person" />
</form>
```